# Proving that something is a second rank tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I am stuck on the following question:
If $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, show that $T_{ij} = E_i E_j + B_i B_j - \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}(E_k E_k + B_k B_k)$ is a second rank tensor.

The only thing that seems useful here is the transformation rule for a rank 2 tensor which says $T'_{ij} = R_{ik}R_{jl}T_{kl}$, but even with this I don't know how it can be used to show that the above is a tensor.

Can I get a hint on where to start?

Edit: How does this seem as a proof?
$R_{ik}R_{jl}T_{kl} = R_{ik}R_{jl}(E_k E_l + B_k B_l + \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}(E_p E_p + B_p B_p)) = R_{ik}R_{jl}E_k E_l + R_{ik}R_{jl} B_k B_l - \frac{1}{2}R_{ik}R_{jl}\delta_{kl}(E_p E_p + B_p B_p) = (R_{ik}E_k)(R_{jl}E_l)+ (R_{ik}B_k)(R_{jl}B_l) - \frac{1}{2} \delta_{ij}(E_k E_k + B_k B_k)$

as $R_{ik}R_{jk}\delta_{kl} = R_{ik}R_{jk} = (RR^T)_{ij} = (I)_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$

Note that $E'_k E'_k = (R_{kj}E_k)(R_{kl}E_l) = R_{kj}R_{kl}E_j E_l = (R^T R)_{jl}E_j E_l = \delta_{ij}E_j E_l = E_k E_k$ (similarly for $B_k B_k$) and so in fact the above expression is the same as that for when $\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{B}$ are transformed individually and we calculate the new matrix using these new transformed vectors.
Therefore $T_{ij}$ is a tensor.

Comment: Essentially, you need to show that forming $T$ from $E$ and $B$ and applying the transform to $T$ gives the same result as applying the transform to $E$ and $B$, then forming a new $T$ from the transformed vectors. This means that this definition of $T$ is properly coordinate-independent.

Comment: I see, thank you. I feel like I sort of understand why this definition ensures $T$ is coordinate-independent but not fully, would you be able to give me an explanation as to how this means $T$ is coordinate-independent?

Comment: Write $\mathbf T=\boldsymbol E\otimes \boldsymbol E+\boldsymbol B\otimes\boldsymbol B-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf I(|\boldsymbol E|^2+|\boldsymbol B|^2)$. Then break the proof into chunks - show first that if $\boldsymbol u$ is a vector, then $\boldsymbol u\otimes \boldsymbol u$ is a tensor. Then show that $|\boldsymbol u|^2$ is a scalar. Apply linearity and done.